# Class from AWS JDK can't be found

Tags: java, spring, maven, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
AmazonSQS amazonSqs = new AmazonSQSClient(new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider());
```

I have the java sdk in my `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

But it won't let me build my java application, and produces the following error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'videoTranscoderService' defined in file     
[XXX/VideoTranscoderService.class]: Instantiation 
of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
com/amazonaws/ClientConfigurationFactory: com.amazonaws.ClientConfigurationFactory 
-> [Help 1]
```

I just can't understand how it can't find the class `ClientConfigurationFactory` because it should be included in the Java SDK right? I appreciate any help you guys can give me to solve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

com.amazonaws.ClientConfigurationFactory is inside aws-java-sdk-core you will need to add this to your list of dependencies in your pom.xml